# Firebase realtime database android cache grows huge

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a few `keepSynced(true)` in my Android application pointing at different firebase db locations. The data in my firebase database is around 20mb, but after a few months of extensive app use, the cache (app data) on the Android phone grows to 1GB+.

How can the cache on device grow many times the original data?

PS: Is there any easy way to debug what's inside my local app cache?

Thanks,

Comment: So you basically say that 1GB+ of data comes only from the Realtime Database? Are you sure isn't related to storing files, such as images or videos?

Comment: No image and video. Its just plain txt. My doubt is that somehow data is duplicated in cache but I can't debug it.